# How can I prevent empty strings in my array from counting as a part of length?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So, I have a JSON file which I fetch. The array `syllables` can hold up to strings max. however, when I leave out (for example) 2 words, I will end up with 2 words and 2 empty strings. However in my front-end when I try to create a check it will still require 4 "strings". So 2 words + 2 times the key "enter" before it says that the `length` equals my JSON. However I want empty strings NOT to be part of the `length`.

How my JSON looks like (I took an example with more words and more `syllables` arrays):

```
{
"main_object": {
"id": "5",
"getExerciseTitle": "TestFor",
"language": "nl_NL",
"application": "lettergrepen",
"main_object": {
  "title": "TestFor",
  "language": "nl_NL",
  "exercises": [
    {
      "word": "test",
      "syllables": [
        "test01",
        "test02",
        "test03",
        ""
      ]
    },
    {
      "word": "tesst",
      "syllables": [
        "test11",
        "test12",
        "",
        ""
      ]
    }
  ]
},
"dataType": "json"
  }
}
```

the piece of code which could cause this:

```
        $.map(exercise.syllables, function (syllable, j) {

        // Code to check if the syllable exists and is not an empty string
       if (!syllable || !syllable.trim().length) {
       // If it doesn't exist or is an empty string, return early without creating/appending elements
           return;
      }

        var innerSylCol = $('<div/>', {
            class: 'col-md-3 inputSyllables'
        });

        var sylInput = $('<input/>', {
            'type': 'text',
            'class': 'form-control syl-input',
            'name':  +c++,
            'id': +idsyll++
        }).on('keyup', function() {
          var cValue = $(this).val();
         if (cValue === syllable) {
         correctSylls.push(cValue);
         console.log(correctSylls);
         }
       if (exercise.syllables.length === correctSylls.length) {
     $(this).closest('.syll-row').find('input.syl-input').addClass('btn btn-success').removeClass('form-control');
      }

   });
```

How the whole code looks like:

```
function createExercise(json) {
const exercises = json.main_object.main_object.exercises;

var exerciseArea = $('<div/>', {
    id: 'exerciseField',
    'class': 'col-md-12'
});

$.map(exercises, function (exercise, i) {

    var exer = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'row form-group',
        'id': +idRow++
    })

    var colLeft = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'col-md-3'
    });

    var row = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'row'
    });

    var audCol = $('<div>', {
        class: 'col-md-3 audioButton'
    }).append(getAudioForWords());

    var wordCol = $('<div>', {
        class: 'col-md-9 ExerciseWordFontSize exerciseWord',
        'id': 'wordInput[' + ID123 + ']', // note to self: the brackets will need to be escaped in later DOM queries
        text: exercise.word
    });
    row.append(audCol, wordCol);
    colLeft.append(row);

    var sylCol = $('<div>', {
        class: 'col-md-9'
    });

    var sylRow = $('<div/>', {
        class: 'row syll-row'
    });

    function getFilterEmptyString() {
        var filtered = syllables.filter(function(str) {
           return str.trim()
        });
        console.log(filtered);
    }

    var correctSylls = [];

    $.map(exercise.syllables, function (syllable, j) {

        // Code to check if the syllable exists and is not an empty string
       if (!syllable || !syllable.trim().length) {
       // If it doesn't exist or is an empty string, return early without creating/appending elements
           return;
      }

        var innerSylCol = $('<div/>', {
            class: 'col-md-3 inputSyllables'
        });

        var sylInput = $('<input/>', {
            'type': 'text',
            'class': 'form-control syl-input',
            'name':  +c++,
            'id': +idsyll++
        }).on('keyup', function() {
            var cValue = $(this).val();
            if (cValue === syllable) {
              correctSylls.push(cValue);
              console.log(correctSylls);
            }
            if (exercise.syllables.length === correctSylls.length) {
              $(this).closest('.syll-row').find('input.syl-input').addClass('btn btn-success').removeClass('form-control');
            }

        });

        innerSylCol.append(sylInput);
        sylRow.append(innerSylCol);
    });
    idsyll = 0;

    sylCol.append(sylRow);

    exer.append(colLeft, sylCol);

    exerciseArea.append(exer);
});
return exerciseArea;
}
```

What I was thinking of, but not entirely sure: Couldn't a loop do this?

Notes: Variables have already been declared etc. I tried to put as much code in that's just related to THIS problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count them with a check for [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) values.

```js
var syllables = ["test11", "test12", "", ""],
    count = syllables.reduce((c, s) => c + Boolean(s), 0);
    
console.log(count);
```

Or create a new array, if needed later and take the length

```js
var syllables = ["test11", "test12", "", ""],
    truthy = syllables.filter(Boolean);
    
console.log(truthy.length);
console.log(truthy);
```

Comment: Ah, I assume I can then just throw this in the loop I already have? EDIT: which one would be recommended?

Comment: if you need an array without empty strings, then take the second approach.

Comment: My apologies, let me clarify real quick: I made a check on my front-end, that will evaluate whether the words filled out by (for example) you equal the words in my JSON, if yes: The input fields will be marked green, if not, red.

Comment: if you already iterate, take a counter and increment with the above boolean check.